# Check for limit infinity of a function

Tags: java, math, junit

A few weeks ago I wrote an exam. The first task was to find the right approximation of a function with the given properties: [Properties of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMYX.png)

I had to check every approximation with the tests i write for the properties. The properties 2, 3 and 4 were no problem. But I don't know how to check for property 1 using a JUnit test written in Java. My approach was to do it this way:

```
@Test
void test1() {
    Double x = 0.01;
    Double res = underTest.apply(x);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        x = rnd(0, x);
        Double lastRes = res;

        res = underTest.apply(x);

        assertTrue(res <= lastRes);
    }
}
```

Where `rnd(0, x)` is a function call that generates a random number within (0,x].
But this can't be the right way, because it is only checking for the x's getting smaller, the result is smaller than the previous one. I.e. the test would also succeed if the first `res` is equal to -5 and the next a result little smaller than the previous for all 100000 iterations. So it could be that the result after the 100000 iteration is -5.5 (or something else). That means the test would also succeed for a function where the right limit to 0 is -6. Is there a way to check for property 1?

Comment: What does `rnd(0, x)` do or what is it meant to do? Why don't you use large numbers for `x` instead, e.g. `x *= 10.0` each iteration?

Comment: @petrov.aleksandr No, this is not my question

Comment: @Thomas x must be getting smaller for each iteration. rnd(0, x) just returns a new value which is 0 < x (new) <= x (old). So, it just makes x smaller (or if unlucky equal) than the previous x. It could be substituted by something like x = 1/i (i != 0).

Comment: I like the question but I don't like the example. Would be much better for the overall Q&A if it was e.g. *f(x) = x* and the test "would need to test" if it goes to infinity with growing *x*.

Comment: Well, starting with a negative `x` multiplying it with 10 would always result in a smaller value, e.g. -0.0001 * 10 = -0.001 (then -0.01, -0.1, -1, -10 etc.).

Comment: @Thomas If `x` was allowed to be negative it would work, but as property 1 says x must go to 0 from the positive end (right-sided limit)

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case `x /= 10.0` should do the trick or even just `x /= 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to check for property 1?

Trivially? No, of course not. Calculus is all about what happens at infinity / at infinitely close to any particular point – where basic arithmetic gets stuck trying to divide a number that grows ever tinier by a range that is ever smaller, and basic arithmetic can't do '0 divided by 0'.

Computers are like basic arithmetic here, or at least, you are applying basic arithmetic in the code you have pasted, and making the computer do actual calculus is considerably more complicated than what you do here. As in, years of programming experience required more complicated; I very much doubt you were supposed to write a few hundred thousand lines of code to build an entire computerized math platform to write this test, surely.

More generally, you seem to be labouring under the notion that a test proves anything.

They do not. **A test cannot prove correctness, ever**. Just like science can never prove anything, they can only disprove (and can build up ever more solid foundations and confirmations which any rational person usually considers more than enough so that they will e.g. take as given that the Law of Gravity will hold, even if there is no proof of this and there never will be).

A test can only prove that you have a bug. It can never prove that you don't.

Therefore, anything you can do here is merely a shades of gray scenario: You can make this test catch *more* scenarios where you know the `underTest` algorithm is incorrect, but it is impossible to catch all of them.

What you have pasted is already useful: This test proves that as you use double values that get ever closer to 0, your test ensures that the output of the function grows ever smaller. That's worth something. You seem to think this particular shade of gray isn't dark enough for you. You want to show that it gets fairly close to infinity.

That's... your choice. You cannot PROVE that it gets to infinity, because computers are like basic arithmetic with some approximation sprinkled in.

There isn't a heck of a lot you can do here: Yes, you can test if the final `res` value is for example 'less than -1000000'. You can even test if it is literally negative infinity, but there is no guarantee that this is even correct; a function that is defined as 'as the input goes to 0 from the positive end, the output will tend towards negative infinity' is free to do so only for an input so incredibly tiny, that double cannot represent it at all (computers are not magical; doubles take 64 bit, that means there are at most 2^64 unique numbers that `double` can even represent. 2^64 is a very large number, but it is **nothing** compared to the doubly-dimensioned infinity that is the concept of 'all numbers imaginable' (there are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, and an infinite amount of such numbers across the whole number line, after all). Thus, there are plenty of very tiny numbers that `double` just cannot represent. At all.

For your own sanity, using randomness in a unit test is a bad idea, and for some definitions of the word 'unit test', literally broken (some labour under the notion that unit tests must be reliable or they cannot be considered a unit test, and this is not such a crazy notion if you look at what 'unit test' pragmatically speaking ends up being used for: To have test environments automatically run the unit tests, repeatedly and near continuously, in order to flag down ASAP when someone breaks one. If the CI server runs a unit test 1819 times a day, it would get quite annoying if by sheer random chance, one in 20k times it fails; it would then assume the most recent commit is to blame and no framework out there I know of repeats a unit test a few more times. In the end programming works best if you move away from the notion of proofs and cold hard definitions, and move towards 'do what the community thinks things mean'. For unit tests, that means: Don't use randomness).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: you cannot reliably test ANY of the properties

- function f could break one of the properties in a point x which is not even representable as a double due to limited precision
- there is too much points too test, realistically you need to pick a subset of the domain

Secondly:
your definition of a limit is wrong. You check that the function is monotonically decreasing. This is not required by limit definition - the function could fluctuate when approaching the limit. In the general case, I would probably follow [Weierstrass definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_and_related_statements)

But:
By eyeballing the conditions you can quickly notice that a logarithmic function (with any base) meets the criteria. (so the function is indeed monotonically decreasing).

Let's pick natural logarithm, and check its value at smallest x that can be represented as a double:

```
System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(Math.log(Double.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println(Math.log(Double.MIN_VALUE) < -1000);

// prints
4.9E-324
-744.4400719213812
false
```

As you can see, the value is circa -744, which is really far from minus infinity. You cannot get any closer on double represented on 64 bits.